# Compare a running process in memory with an executable in disk

Tags: linux, memory, process

I have a big project which will load an executable (let's call it **greeting**) into memory, but for some reason (e.g. there are many files called **greeting** under different directories), I need to know if the process in memory is exactly the one I want to use.

I know how to compare two files: diff, cmp, cksum and so on. But is there any way to compare a process in memory with an executable in hard disk?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197854/how-does-the-proc-pid-exe-symlink-differ-from-ordinary-symlinks) you can get the contents of the memory version of the binary from the proc file system.  I think you can cksum the original and the in memory version.

> According to the man page of /proc, under Linux 2.2 and later, the
>   file is a symbolic link containing the actual pathname of the executed
>   command. Apparently, the binary is loaded into memory, and
>   /proc/[pid]/exe points to the content of the binary in memory.

Comment: however, doesn't this fail on machines with MPU/MMUs?

Comment: I am really not sure what proc looks like with multiple processors.  Can the PID be duplicated if it does?  Interesting question.  I don't think PIDs would be duplicated?  Am I understanding MPU and MMU correctly?